# Power Pivot - Average time per item

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table, powerpivot

I'm trying to calculate on average, how long it takes to make each item.

Here is the data table:

```
Date        Item    Quantity   Operator
01/01/2014  Item1   3          John
01/01/2014  Item2   5          John
02/01/2014  Item1   7          Bob
02/01/2014  Item2   4          John
03/01/2014  Item1   2          Bob
07/01/2014  Item2   3          John
```

On 01/01/2014 John made 3 of `Item 1` and 5 of `Item 2`. If we only had the first 2 rows we can guess that it takes 0.375 days to make `Item 1` and 0.625 days to make `Item 2`.

I want to be able to calculate this on average using all the data and taking in to account the operators obviously working on different items.

Thank you

Comment: If we only had the first two rows, we **can't** say how long John spent on Item1 or Item2. It could be 3 x 5 minutes on Item1 and the rest of the time on Item2. *If* you wanted to calculate that working hours per Item and per item type, then you would solve for production times using the solver and linear modeling (sum of all quatities times items per day = 8 for all workers on all working days). I understand your data is an example, but based on row 4, you'd say John can make 4 item2's per day, but on row 6 he only makes 3 per day, while on row 1+2 he makes  5 of them and **also** 3 item1's.

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel's [Solver](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introduction-to-optimization-with-the-excel-solver-tool-HA001124595.aspx) I was able to find the production times per item that best fits (in terms of squared error) the data. Do so that, prepare your worksheet as follows (assuming the data you gave is in columns A-D):

- In J1 put the label "Working hours per day:"
- In K1 punt the number of working hours per day (for example 8).
- In J3 put the label "Production times per item:"
- In J4 put the label "Item1" and in J5 "Item2"
- Set some initial values in K4 and K5 (for example 1 and 2).
- In column E add the "Production time" using the formula in E2: `=VLOOKUP(B2;$J$4:$K$5;2;FALSE)*C2` and copy-paste it down, which calculates the production time per item times the quantity of items.
- In column F add the "Worker-Day ID" using the forluma in F2: `A2&D2` and copy-paste it down, which creates an unique ID for every day a worker had worked (we need that to add the working hours per day in column G).
- In Column G add the "Working hours per day" using the formula in G2: `SUMIF($F$2:$F$7;F2;$E$2:$E$7)`
- In column H add the "Working hours deviation squared" using the formula in H2: `(G2-$K$1)^2`
- Finally add a grand total of column H by putting in H8: `SUM(H2:H7)`

Now start the solver an minimize `H8` by changing `K4:K5`. This essentially tries to find the best production times per item that explains the production per day.

Mathematically there are some caveats and pitfalls, but it (more or less) answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's very helpful insight into the problem. Unfortunately it seems unfeasible when you increase the product count. Solver has a limit of 200 and even that takes a while. Is there any better way to arrive at a production time?

Comment: You can create a pivot table which counts the days and the total items created per item and per worker. Then solve the problem based on that data. That is even more robust than the method I described. Note that Excel doesn't update pivot data while solving, so stay clear from putting data in the pivot that depends on the to-be-optimized data.

Answer (score 0):

I started looking at a Power Pivot solution based on your sample data, but quickly realized you havent included nearly enough info about how to calculate your result. I would read the first two rows as indicating it takes 0.125 days per Item (i.e. a Quantity of 1 for any Item).

And how is it supposed to work once the first 4 lines are considered, with gaps and other operators?  What about the gaps in the days e.g. 4th 5th 6th? Please add in your expected results for all scenarios and explain your calculation method.

Anyway I've built a working prototype to start the discussion.  You can try it out using my demo file: "Power Pivot demo - average time per item.xlsx" in my One Drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398

My DAX calculation is:

Average Days per Item := DISTINCTCOUNT( [Date] ) / SUM( [Quantity] )